# Finite closed set

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let be $(X,\tau)$ a compact space and $Z=\{x \in X : \{x\}\in \tau \}$.
Prove that $F \subseteq Z$ is closed in $X$, then $F$ is finite.

I don't know if what I proved is correct. Here it is what I've done:

*$F \subseteq Z \Rightarrow F=\{x_1,x_2,...\}$, note that* *$F=\bigcup\limits_{\substack{\{x_i\}\in\tau\\ i=1,2,..}}\{x_i\}$.Then $F$ is open.*

*Take $C=\{\{x\}: x \in X \wedge\{x\} \in \tau\}$.
Note that $F\subseteq \bigcup C$, so $C$ is a open recovering of F.*

*If $F$ is infinite, then there is no finite subfamily $C'$ of $C$ that $F \subseteq \bigcup C'$.*

*So $F$ is finite because $X$ is compact.*

Is that right?

Comment: You can't assume $F$ is countable (at the beginning).

Comment: I don't used that in the proof. It was only to show how F is.

Comment: F is a subset of Z, so it's the union of points $x_{i}$. Because F is closed in X it is compact in X. This means there exist a finite subcover of F. This means F has to be the union of finitely many points $x_{i}$.

Comment: The proof looks good to me. Topology is closed under arbitrary union, so it is fine. Maybe better to denote $\{x_{\alpha}\} \in \tau$ instead to be more clear, but not a big deal.

Comment: Understood. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is closed in $X$ so $F$ is compact.

As $F \subseteq Z$ we know that for all $x \in F$, $\{x\}$ is open.

The cover of singletons $\mathcal{O} = \{\{x\} : x \in F\}$ of $F$ covers $F$ and we cannot omit any member of it or we don't cover $F$ any more. So by compactness of $F$, it has a finite subcover, which only can be $\mathcal{O}$ itself (which thus is finite), and $|F| = |\mathcal{O}|$, so $F$ is finite.